# Replace all instances of a character within context

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regex-lookarounds

The below is an example of a very large text file that I have:

```
@Don't replace this line: <http://nomatch.com#>
/or this line!/

<http://example.com#Example/Replace/With/Underscores> and <http://example.com#Example/Replace/With/Underscores2> 

</Nothing to replace on this line either./>
```

I would like to replace all instances of `/` (forward slash) on each line after `<http://example.com#Example/` and before `>`. Therefore, the resulting file should look like:

```
@Don't replace this line: <http://nomatch.com#>
/or this line!/

<http://example.com#Example_Replace_With_Underscores> and <http://example.com#Example_Replace_With_Underscores>

</Nothing to replace on this line either./>
```

So far I have come up with the regex: `(?=.*?>)/`, but this is grabbing every `/` on a line with a `>` ([link to example](https://regexr.com/5l9ki)). At the moment I'm using VSCode to perform the find and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?<=<http://example\.com#Example/[^>]*)/(?=[^>]*>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kFYzAs/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=<http://example\.com#Example/[^>]*)` - a positive lookbehind that makes there is a `<http://example.com#Example/` string followed with any zero or more chars other than `>` as many as possible immediately to the left of the current location
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?=[^>]*>)` - a positive lookahead (if you need to make sure there is a closing `>`) that makes there there are zero or more chars other than `>`  and then a `>` char immediately to the right of the current location.

See Visual Studio Code demo and settings:

[image]